# DB2 Declare/Set Variable in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I can't get this stored procedure to compile, I simply want to declare and set one variable that will be used in the proc. NOTE: shipNo is the only incoming parameter, and is VARCHAR(32).

```
P1: BEGIN
DECLARE @likeShipNo VARCHAR(32);
SET likeShipNo = '%' || shipNo || '%';

DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR
    SELECT ADV_SHIP_NOTICE_NO,
        VNDR_ID,
        LOC,
        CARR_CD,
        CARR_PRO_NO,
        BL_NO,
        SHIP_EQUIP_ID,
        TS_LOAD

        FROM TRITS

        WHERE ADV_SHIP_NOTICE_NO LIKE(@likeShipNo); 
OPEN cursor1;
END P1
```

Comment: What is with the cryptically abbreviated column names? Why not just nicely spell them out?

Answer (score 3):

The variables in DB2 doesn't need the @ like in MSSQL. Also, when you return a cursor, you need to add the sentence `RESULT SET 1` before begin and add the `WITH RETURN TO CLIENT` to the cursor that you want to return. The procedure should look like this:

```
CREATE BEGIN MYSCHEMA.MYPROC (
    IN shipNo VARCHAR(30) )
BEGIN
    DECLARE likeShipNo VARCHAR(32);

    SET likeShipNo = '%' || shipNo || '%';

    DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR
        SELECT
            ADV_SHIP_NOTICE_NO,
            VNDR_ID,
            LOC,
            CARR_CD,
            CARR_PRO_NO,
            BL_NO,
            SHIP_EQUIP_ID,
            TS_LOAD
        FROM
            TRITS
        WHERE
            ADV_SHIP_NOTICE_NO LIKE likeShipNo;
    OPEN cursor1;
END;
```

Comment: I had to use CALLER instead of CLIENT just to avoid compiler warnings. Made no difference, still does not compile.

Comment: @Ted I've checked the SP again and fixed a little bug. Please tell me if you have achieved to compile using this way or your own.